# Extract lines matching result from text file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I need to extract the filename from a text file whereas the output on the text file doesn't have fonts.

So as you can see from the output file below I need to print out results where they are no fonts after the first results? So only the last result has fonts in this output

Does this make sense - Would Grep, Sed or Awk be the answer

So need a output from the text file below that shows that no fonts are present in that PDf within the **START and **END

```
******************START***********************
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
/home/user1/Documents/temp1.pdf
******************END***********************
******************START***********************
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
/home/user1/Documents/temp2.pdf
******************END***********************
******************START***********************
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
BAAAAA+TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT        TrueType          yes yes yes     14  0
CAAAAA+TimesNewRomanPSMT             TrueType          yes yes yes      9  0
/home/user3/Documents/temp file.pdf
******************END***********************
```

Comment: How far did you get with the problem?

Comment: Only need filenames of PDF's that contained in the ***START** and ***END** that do not have no fonts mentioned. I'm trying awk at the moment but no joy :-(

Comment: @Grimlockz can you edit your question, add an expected output based on your input example? your comment is not clear to me either. "that do not have no fonts mentioned."....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prints any line containing ".pdf" if the previous line starts with `-`.

```
[me@home]$ awk '{if (st && match($0,".pdf")){print $0}; st=match($0,"^-")}' in.txt
/home/user1/Documents/temp1.pdf
/home/user1/Documents/temp2.pdf
```

It is not a generic solution, but will work with the input data you've given. I can imagine several edge cases where this might fail but it's all down to the specifications of your input file.

---

#### Update

(Based on the script you've posted in the comments below) If what you're trying to do is simply to identify PDF files that have no embedded fonts, this might work:

```
MAGNUM="/mnt/network/User\ 1\ PDF\ 06.12.11/"
has_no_fonts() {
    COUNT=$(pdffonts "$1" 2> /dev/null | wc -l)
    exit $(( $COUNT - 4 ))
}
export -f has_no_fonts
find "$MAGNUM" -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec bash -c 'has_no_fonts "{}"' \; -print
```

Here's a breakdown of the script:

- Detecting embedded font count. Would have been simple if `pdffonts` returned a specific value if no fonts were embedded but that is not so. We therefore count the number of output lines and deduct 2 (header lines) to determine the number of embedded fonts

  ```
  COUNT=$(pdffonts "$1" 2> /dev/null | wc -l) # number of output lines
                                              # exactly 2 if no fonts
                                              # exactly 0 if there are errors
  exit $(( $COUNT - 2 ))  # exit 0 (success) if and only if PDF has no fonts
  ```
- bash function exported so it can be used in subshell.

  ```
  export -f has_no_fonts
  ```
- Locate pdf files and only print out name if PDF valid and has no fonts

  ```
  find .....  -exec bash -c 'has_no_fonts "{}"' \; -print
                    -------                        -------
                        |                             |
            -exec cannot run bash functions     Will only print 
             so run in a bash subshell       filename if prev command exit with 0
  ```

If you prefer a one-line, the whole script can be written as:

```
find "$MAGNUM" -name "*.pdf" \
    -exec bash -c 'exit $(($(pdffonts "{}" 2> /dev/null |wc -l) - 2))' \; -print
```

Comment: Cheers testing this now and it seems to work thanks - `#!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
MAGNUM=/mnt/network/User\ 1\ PDF\ 06.12.11/
for f in $(find $MAGNUM -type f -name "*.pdf")
do
echo "******************START***********************"
pdffonts $f
echo "$f"
echo "******************END***********************"
done > output.txt
# restore $IFS
IFS=$SAVEIFS`  this is the script for getting the PDF info if that helps

Comment: @Grimlockz Glad it helped. BTW, it might help others readers if you updated your question with that script to show the origin of the input file and what you're trying to achieve. P.S. see updated answer for alternative solution (assuming you're not using `output.txt` for anything else).

Comment: Thanks very much and noted, will update going forward - with the new script it looks awesome but its have trouble finding the folder due to the spaces in the filename of folders :-(

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed -n '/^\*/,//{H;/\*END\*/{x;s/\n/&/6;t;s|[^/]*\([^\n]*\).*|\1|p}}' in.txt
/home/user1/Documents/temp1.pdf
/home/user1/Documents/temp2.pdf
```

Explanation:

1. Focus on lines between lines beginning with `*`
2. Store such lines in the hold space (HS).
3. When we reach the closing delimiter swap to the HS.
4. Check for 6 or more newlines i.e. entries that must have fonts and if so bailout.
5. Delete all non-essential text and print out.

Or at a pinch:

```
sed -n '/^\*/,//{H;/\*END\*/{x;s|[^/]*-\n\(/[^\n]*\).*|\1|p}}' in.txt
```